# Overriding Excerpt in WordPress with Advanced Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm new to WordPress and we have a form that people can fill out to submit posts onto our site.

We used Advanced Custom Fields plugin to fill out all the necessary information we needed. We have on field that is story_description.

I would like to make that story_description to use all the excerpt filters (length, etc) and save it under the post_excerpt in the wp_posts table.

How would I go about having that save in that table with the custom length and the other specific in the excerpt that are defined? I'm new to all the filters and actions.

Is there a way to just overwrite is and treat is like a normal excerpt when the post is saved?

I appreciate any responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your first need to add the following to allow excerpt generation outside of the loop (this go in your theme *functions.php*):

```
function rw_trim_excerpt( $text='' )
{
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
    return wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
}
add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', 'rw_trim_excerpt');
```

This  function comes from [jlengstorf answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37659/62744).

Then when you insert your post do the following:

```
wp_insert_post(array(
    // ... other stuffs ...
    post_excerpt => apply_filters('get_the_excerpt', $story_description)
));
```

This will filter your `$story_description` string with all the excerpt WP functions.